# Getting difficulty in removing database in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using SQLite database in my application.I want to remove/delete the database but unable to do so.I have checked the location of the database and it is present at /data/data/org.secure.sms/databases but when i tried to delete it,it was not successful.Please help me.
This is the code:

```
public static void DeleteDatabase(Context context)
{
    try
    {

    String filePath = context.getFilesDir()+ File.separator + "contactsManager";
    String filePath1 = context.getFilesDir()+ File.separator + "database";
    String filePath2 = context.getFilesDir()+ File.separator + "databases";

    context.deleteDatabase(filePath);
    context.deleteDatabase(filePath1);
    context.deleteDatabase(filePath2);

    File file = new File(filePath);
    File file1 = new File( filePath1 );

context.deleteFile(file.getName());
context.deleteFile(file1.getName());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Exception in DeleteDatabase",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please provide error stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this to delete my database, which is from a custom class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "pain.db";

private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME;


@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

        Log.d("DATABASE UPDATED", "DATABASE UPDATED");

        try {
            File file = new File(DB_PATH);
            file.delete();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For deleting the database, this one is the code:

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

In your code you are providing complete path.

Comment: sir i have provided complete path but i am getting this message in logcat:

Comment: 10-16 15:15:44.578: D/(9319): unable to unlink '/data/data/org.secure.sms/files/contactsManager': No such file or directory (errno=2)
10-16 15:15:44.607: D/(9319): unable to unlink '/data/data/org.secure.sms/files/database': No such file or directory (errno=2)

Comment: @YaqubAhmad : FYI check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#deleteDatabase%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @user1726619 : as error itself explains the database you are trying to delete is not present. Either path is wrong or try to add extension `.db` to your database name.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `file Extension` !!
Try below:

```
String filePath = context.getFilesDir()+ File.separator + "yourDataBaseName.db";
```